# CallKit is not showing Incoming UI when Device is Locked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, callkit

I am developing a voip app, which uses Callkit to show System UI for incoming calls.

To test the incoming call, I triggered it from my app like below

```
let callHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: "+9197xxxxxxxx")
let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle
callUpdate.supportsDTMF = true
callUpdate.supportsHolding = true
callUpdate.supportsGrouping = false
callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = false
callUpdate.hasVideo = false
UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask {
    print("Error")
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
    self.callKitProvider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: callUpdate) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

which works fine when app is in foreground, but when I put the device in locked state it throws error as "Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.incomingcall Code=3 "(null)""

Please help. Thanks in Adavance!

Comment: Do you have active "Do not Disturb" in iPhone and it is set to Always?

Comment: Thanks @AntonioM No it is turned off.

Comment: I tested our app with Callkit in background and it works well with lock screen (therefor, dispatchqueue will doesn't work). Maybe iOS close app after go background and lock screen, try that iOS doesn't close app after go background using background tasks. Other option is use Apple push to wake up the app and after report the call, we use last option.

Comment: Thanks, it worked... As you said, it was due to accidentally activating DND.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DND was the problem as @AntonioM suggested in the comments, Switching it off works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the info.plist? Required background modes -> 'App provides Voice over IP services' requested.

Comment: Emm, since it works fine in foreground, you must have set it. Over look at CallKit.CXError   public typealias _ErrorType = CXErrorCodeIncomingCallError
        case unknown
        case unentitled
        case callUUIDAlreadyExists
        case filteredByDoNotDisturb
        case filteredByBlockList

Comment: Thanks, But it was not a problem with CallKit but I accidentally set DND mode.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 15** Onwards: Apart from ***DND*** mode, you might get this error when your [***Focus*** mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608)(Personal/Work/Sleep/Driving/Gaming/Fitness/Custom) is switched ON. But, you can still get the call based on your ***Focus*** notifications preference(People/Apps).